# which UrlEncode or HtmlEncode in .Net we should use?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, url-encoding

I find many method in .net can provide `UrlEncode`
such like:

1. `System.Net.WebUtility`
2. `Uri.EscapeDataString` or `Uri.EscapeUriString`
3. `System.Text.Encodings.Web.UrlEncoder`

For `HtmlEncode`:

1. `System.Net.WebUtility`
2. `System.Text.Encodings.Web.HtmlEncoder`

And My Question is: which one is recommended?

Comment: `WebUtility` is in `.NET Standard`, `UrlEncoder`/`HtmlEncoder` is `.NET Core` only.

Comment: @IlyaChumakov UrlEncoder/HtmlEncoder is in a nuget package `System.Text.Encodings.Web` , and it target .netStandard 1.0 , any library can reference this package.   which one we should use most ?

Comment: You're right! And apisof.net info is incorrect cause it shows `.NET Core` only https://apisof.net/catalog/System.Text.Encodings.Web. Sorry, I have no answer to your question.